# Regex to return string left of character, if any, else right of character

Tags: regex

I am relatively new to working with regex. I have a specific task I'd like to achieve but after searching/experimenting most of the afternoon am having a hard time figuring out the regex to get there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Say I have a string `abc|123` where `abc` and `123` are variables and are of variable length. I want to return `abc` unless it is empty, in which case I'd prefer to return `123`. The pipe `|` just serves a delimiter, and is not strictly necessary here, but I thought it could assist in differentiating between the two strings as "left of pipe" and "right of pipe". Any ideas?

Comment: you haven't specified what language you are using... but you can use a simple string.split and split your string on | char.

Comment: If only it were that easy! Unfortunately I'm dealing with a web application that only allows regex entry via a text input.

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Is this what you're after: [`(.+)\|(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/0hhstx/1)?

Comment: `(^.+(?=\|))|((?<=^\|).+)` might be necessary if it does `/g` (multiple matches) by default, which several do...

Comment: zzxyz, that one did exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by `return`, try using this:

`[^|]+`

The first match will be what you want, that is if input is `abc|123` then it's gonna be `abc`, if input is `|123` then first match will be `123`. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JtBSsO/1)

I was once doing some `drag-and-drop` programming and it had validation based on regex, and something like this worked for me.